# preg match multiline strings

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I have tried this to remove anything from  to  tags.

```
    $contents = "<object>
    fdsfdsfds</object>";

     $contents = preg_replace('#(<object[^>]*>)(.*?)(</object>)#xium', '', $contents);
```

But it does not work.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `s` or DOTALL mode

Comment: You forgot the `s` modifier. `#xium` => `#ius` (`x` and `m` are redundant in your pattern).

Comment: If you mean print only **fdsfdsfds**.Works fine